# Midpoints of three segments are collinear associated with the Pappus configuration

Tags: plane-geometry

I am looking for proof of a problem as follows:

Let three points $A, B, C$ are collinear. Let three lines $a, a_1, a_2 $ through $A$, three lines $b, b_1, b_2 $ through $B$
three lines $c, c_1,c_2$ through $C$. Such that $a_1 \parallel b_2; b_1 \parallel c_2, c_1 \parallel a_2 $. Let $A_1=a \cap b_1, A_2=a\cap c_2$
$B_1=b\cap c_1, B_2=b \cap a_2$, $C_1=c \cap a_1, C_2=c \cap b_2$. Then show that midpoints of $A_1C_2, B_1A_2, C_1B_2$ are collinear.

The problem on configuration of [the Pappus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_hexagon_theorem)

See also: [Elementary proof of a triangular grid lemma](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208292/elementary-proof-of-a-triangular-grid-lemma)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us fix all direction of lines and move the point $C$ along the black line. We see that all points linearly depend from the position of $C$, therefore it is sufficient to check the statement for point $C=A$, $B$ and the infinity. This is not very hard, for example we see, that direction of the segment connecting midpoints of $A_1C_2$ and $B_2C_1$ does not change.